# Need help for a big mistake with my ETH - please (Get 10% for a solution)

Tags: contract-debugging

i´m Soeren.
i was thinking this is the right way to get DAO token with Ether because i have found this tutorial:
https://www.ethereum.org/token4

And with all of this codes (very complex for me) i have searched/google this code for a non-developer (thats me) and found this code in my text below on a website and copy that.
So i created a contract with this code and my ETH and the transaction failed but my ETH are now away and the transaction waits for more gas but i can't edit the contract to change the GAS or something. The contract is in my wallet but not successful and i can't edit it and my ethers are away.

My detailed post: https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/12121/help-created-a-contract-with-a-amount-of-ethers-and-can-t-delete-the-contract-and-don-t-get-back

Is it possible to cancel this contract and get my ETH back???

Thanks in advance to everyone!
Soeren

Comment: Hello, what actually happened? you tried to deploy a contract and the transaction failed? if so the ether you paid for gas (the transaction fees) are gone and you won't see them ever again. By when you're playing around with new concepts like that, try to deploy your token to a testnet instead of the actual ethereum network. Also please can you provide the transaction ID of the transaction you're talking about?

Comment: Can you provide more details? None of the links is working.